# Understanding the practical uses of InitialContext in java?

Tags: java, lookup

I have worked most on the legacy projects where i spot this line `ctx.lookup("datasource");` many number of times. As per usage I have encountered with Initial context , it is used to get the java object binded with some name in webserver/appserver.

- For example, we create datasource thru admin console of weblogic then we can use that object programmaticaly in java program with ctx.lookup("datasource"). If I recall correctly I saw this kind of code during EJB implementation also somewhere where some object that was binded with some name in server itself.

Java docs says When the initial context is constructed, its environment is initialized with properties defined in the environment parameter passed to the constructor. So probably the usage I mentioned earlier, Initial context gets constructed with environment parameters(which probably means objects which admin has created in server like datasource, connection pool if any). This is the just  one use I could relate initial context.

**Please let me know the if it is correct and right usage of initial context class?**

**Basically with initial context , we can bind/lookup java object with same name. In case of webserver/appserver probably the objects like datasource,connection pool get binded by the server at the time of start up and we can look up them straightaway?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a correct use of the context class. In newer EJB implementations you can also use the `@EJB` and `@PersistenceContext` annotations. For a deeper understanding read the wikipedia article about [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).